# No Basic/Standard/Premium options for SQL Azure database

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

I am willing to switch to new Standard SQL Azure database tier, but there is just no such option in my Azure Portal. I have only the option between Web and Business. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be because these services are still in `Preview` mode and you have not enabled this in your subscription. I'm also seeing the same behavior in my subscription. To enable this, please visit [`https://account.windowsazure.com/PreviewFeatures`](https://account.windowsazure.com/PreviewFeatures) and click on `try it now` button next to `New Service Tiers for SQL Databases`.

[image]

Comment: After you sign up, you receive an email saying you are all set, but if you go back to the page you may see "status - You are Queued")