# Azure REST API - Unable to create SQL Azure db with edition type of "Basic"

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a sql azure database via the rest api and am having some trouble with it. I am able to create a database of edition type *Web* but if I try to create one of type *Basic* i get a 400 bad request. I have tried including ServiceObjectiveId which matches *Basic* (all this from the docs - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505701.aspx) but I still get a 400 bad request.

Incidentally, the docs state that ServiceObjectiveId is a required field however I can omit it when I set the edition to *Web*.

The config I am trying looks like this where *edition* is *Web* or *Basic*:

```
const string maxSizeBytes = "10737418240";
const string collationName = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS";
const string serviceObjectiveId = "dd6d99bb-f193-4ec1-86f2-43d3bccbc49c";
var xmlBody = String.Format(
    "<ServiceResource xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\">"
    + "<Name>{0}</Name>"
    + "<Edition>{1}</Edition>"
    //+ "<MaxSizeBytes>{2}</MaxSizeBytes>"
    + "<CollationName>{3}</CollationName>"
    //+ "<ServiceObjectiveId>{4}</ServiceObjectiveId>"
    + "</ServiceResource>", _databaseName, _edition, maxSizeBytes, collationName, serviceObjectiveId);
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think basic is still in preview. Can you create a basic db manually on your account? Have you enabled the db preview features?

Comment: You know what.. I can't :) Damn documentation is leading me astray. It also repeats multiple times that Web and Basic are going to be decommissioned next year. How does one enable preview features?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231092/no-basic-standard-premium-options-for-sql-azure-database.

Comment: So the answer was that I need to enable preview features.. which became release features this morning so this issue is redundant. @AlexC if you would like to post ur comment as answer i'll give it a tick.